# postman error cannot read property role of null

Tags: javascript, postman

```
exports.authorizeRoles = (...roles) => {
  return (req, res, next) => {
    if (!roles.includes(req.user.role)) {
      return next(
        new ErrorHander(
          `Role: ${req.user.role} is not allowed to access this resouce `,
          403
        )
      );
    }

    next();
  };
};
```

Comment: it would be helpful to see how you are using it

Comment: help how to fix that

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add more details about your code, some comments about what you are trying to do and where are you stuck.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says `Cannot read property role of null` which means that `req.user` is `null`. You'll need to understand how the `user` object in the request is supposed to get filled in.  But if it's valid that it might be missing you can change your code like this and it should work better:

```js
exports.authorizeRoles = (...roles) => {
  return (req, res, next) => {
    if (!req.user || !roles.includes(req.user.role)) {
      return next(
        new ErrorHander(
          `Role: ${req.user ? req.user.role : 'undefined'} is not allowed to access this resource `,
          403
        )
      );
    }

    next();
  };
};
```

Comment: "success": false,
    "message": "Role: undefined is not allowed to access this resource "

Comment: that's good - if the role isn't provided in the request then this is the correct message. If you want the role to be present then you'll need to figure out how to get the req.user object defined and containing a proper 'role' value.

Comment: how we get to know

Comment: if you're asking how to find out how the req.user object gets created, that would depend on your server receiving the request and how it does user management. That's beyond the scope of your question and specific to your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

const decodedData = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);

req.user = await User.findById(decodedData._id);

next();
});

Replace the above code by

const decodedData = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);

req.user = await User.findById(decodedData.id);

next();
});

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).